# How to show text only on mobile with CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

I have a text (in a div) which shows on desktop and mobile screens.

**Expected**

I want the text to only show in `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)`

**How to**

1. hide the div with `display:none` *or*
2. is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use media query.

Set `display:none` to div and then apply `display:block` for mobile using **max-width** media query.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

or you can use the **min-width** media query. Less code here

***Stack Snippet***

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  div {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: I'd simplify this by putting `display: none` in the media query triggered at `min-width: 768.1px`. This way you only need the media query, and don't have (1) to reset the default display on the element only to (2) reverse it back with a media query.

Comment: @denmch thank you it worked! How to set the question as answered?

Comment: @denmch Agreed....I have used the `max-width` because OP had mentioned in the question that he want to use `max-width` only....BTW I have also added the `min-width` solution...

Comment: Thank you @BhuwanBhatt I am inexperienced and I am having a hard time dealing with media queries. Have a great day.

Comment: @ElPistolero The two options are functionally equivalent, so Bhuwan Bhatt should keep the accepted answer. Good luck moving forward and keep asking questions!

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me or i couldn't figure it out.
so i used this..

CSS

```
.hideonphone{ display: none;}
   @media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px){ .hideonphone{ display: inline;}}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="hideonphone"> The text goes here</div>
```

Maybe is the same solution but i'm inexperienced.